# How to convert these sql code to yii

Tags: mysql, yii

My code for joining the two tables with showing the null values.

Please convert these code to Yii format

My sql Left outer join code

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_pms_project LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_pms_percentage
ON tbl_pms_project.intProjectId = tbl_pms_percentage.intProjectId;
```

Convert to the yii format.
Kindly help me.
Try to fix this.

Comment: Use relations for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place it to your project model

```
class Project extends CActiveRecord
{
......
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'percentage'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Percentage', array('intProjectId' => 'intProjectId')),
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the join type in relations with joinType like below:

```
return array(
  'project'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'tbl_pms_project',array('intProjectId'=>'intProjectId'),'joinType'=>'LEFT OUTER JOIN'
), 
);
```

AND

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;  
$criteria->with = array('project');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Relations in Yii for achieving your requirement. Read more at [Relational Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr)

In your model for table 'tbl_pms_project' you should define a relation to tbl_pms_percentage as following

```
class Project extends CActiveRecord
{
    ......
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'percentage'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Percentage', array('intProjectId' => 'intProjectId')),
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can use this relation when ever you need the data like given below.

```
$project = Project::model()->findByPk(1);
$project->percentage;
```